# Map from the time-to-sample table to seconds in MP4

Tags: video, mp4

My video file is 11.10 minutes long, with a time scale of 600, a duration of 403701. Which makes perfect sense, given that 11.2 * 60 = 403701 / 600.

On the other hand the time-to-sample table `(stts)` has one entry (the video has a constant frame rate) with count 16116 and duration 4004. And no edit list.

Shouldn't the sum of the duration of the samples add to the length of the movie in the time scale defined in the movie header?

Answer (score 1):

In mp4, each track can have its own timebase. You will find it in the `mdhd` box.